# C++ syntax for using a vector of objects with references

Tags: c++, class, vector, reference

I've been using C for quite a while, but am wanting to use C++ object oriented styling for a current project because of some complexity that seems more appropriate for that approach. So, I'm rather a newbie to best practices in C++ and I'm hoping someone can help me figure out how to do this hopefully straightforward thing.

I spent the last week reading this site and tutorials learning about references, passing them to functions, initializing static class members inside another class, and a bunch of other stuff that I'm really happy to know, but while I think I get at a beginner level the basic ideas of each, I'm having a hard time following how to put it all together.

Here is the thought experiment program I wrote to test my conceptual understanding.

In here, I define a "Button" class, with a few currently trivial members.

I then define a "Wand" class, which is conceptually a way to organize the buttons into a group of buttons.

EDIT: Based on the helpful reply from Steven, I've updated my code to try his suggested layout. It makes good sense to me. I fixed some little things I think might have been typos, but I think there is something subtle about .back that I'm doing wrong. I subbed "String" for std::string because it's an Arduino.

```
#include <vector>

class Button {
  private:
    bool _active;
    String _title;
    float _value;
  public:
    Button(String title, float value) : _title(title) , _value(value) {}
    void setButton(bool active) {
      _active = active;
    };
    String getTitle(void) {
      return _title;
    };
    float getValue(void) {
      return _value;
    };
    void setValue(float newvalue) {
       _value = newvalue;
    };
};

class Wand {
  private:
    std::vector<Button> _Buttons;
    int _numButtons;
  public:
    Wand() {};
    Button& addButton(String title, float value) {
      _Buttons.push_back(Button(title, value));
      return _Buttons.back();
    }
    Button& getButton(int number) {
      return _Buttons[number];
    };
    int numButtons(void) {
      return _Buttons.size();
    };
};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  SerialUSB.begin(9600);

  Wand wand = Wand();
  Button& OkButton = wand.addButton("Okay Button", 0);
  Button& NokayButton = wand.addButton("Nokay Button", 0);
  while(1) {
    SerialUSB.println(wand.getButton(0).getTitle() + "(via Wand): "+ wand.getButton(0).getValue());
    SerialUSB.println(OkButton.getTitle() + "(via Button): "+ OkButton.getValue());
    SerialUSB.println(wand.getButton(1).getTitle() + "(via Wand): "+ wand.getButton(1).getValue());
    SerialUSB.println(NokayButton.getTitle() + "(via Button): "+ NokayButton.getValue());

    OkButton.setValue(OkButton.getValue()+1);
    NokayButton.setValue(NokayButton.getValue()-1);
    delay(500);
  }

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

What's really strange to me now is despite the seemingly parallel structure for the two buttons, the response I get from the monitor is like this:

```
(via Wand): 0.00
(via Button): 15.00
(via Wand): -15.00
(via Button): -15.00
(via Wand): 0.00
(via Button): 16.00
(via Wand): -16.00
(via Button): -16.00
```

Clearly I'm correctly updating and accessing the second button, but the first seems to have created two instances of the class again, the one in the wand which is not being updated and the referenced version which is.

ORIGINAL POST:

Now, I've read about std::vector and it seems like a natural way to store a dynamically allocated array of Buttons inside a Wand. But when I use a member function of Wand to read the value, it is clear that I'm not working with the originally allocated Button objects.

Here in this code, I see the value for the actual button change, but the value when requested through the Button vector is different. I tried throwing in some ampersands, but it mostly just caused compiler errors.

Can anyone show me how to do this kind of thing properly? Or if this is totally the wrong approach, a link to how to learn to do this in a more standard way?

```
#include <vector>

class Button {
  private:
    bool _active;
    char* _title;
    float _value;
  public:
    Button(char* title, float value) : _title(title) , _value(value) {}
    void setButton(bool active) {
      _active = active;
    };
    char* getTitle(void) {
      return _title;
    };
    float getValue(void) {
      return _value;
    };
    void setValue(float newvalue) {
       _value = newvalue;
    };
};

class Wand {
  private:
    std::vector<Button> _Buttons;
    int _numButtons;
  public:
    Wand() {};
    void addButton(Button &newbutton) {
      _Buttons[_numButtons] = newbutton;
      _numButtons++;
    };
    Button& getButton(int number) {
      return _Buttons[number];
    };
    int numButtons(void) {
      return _numButtons;
    };
};


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  SerialUSB.begin(9600);

  Wand wand = Wand();
  Button OkButton = Button("Okay Button", 0);
  Button NokayButton = Button("Nokay Button", 0);
  wand.addButton(OkButton);
  wand.addButton(NokayButton);
  while(1) {
    SerialUSB.println(wand.getButton(0).getValue());
    SerialUSB.println(OkButton.getValue());
    OkButton.setValue(OkButton.getValue()+1);
    SerialUSB.println(wand.getButton(1).getValue());
    SerialUSB.println(NokayButton.getValue());
    NokayButton.setValue(NokayButton.getValue()-1);
    delay(500);
  }

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: If you have a `vector<T>`, that's a dynamically allocated array of `T`-objects. Which means if the storage-array has to grow, all elements must be moved. What you want is either a `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` or (less likely) emplacing in a `list<T>`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will read up on those, but in case this is really trivial and quick to answer:

I tried this from what I read and it's definitely not right. Which things do I need to use make_unique on, and how do I pass unique_ptr referenced objects? `Button OkButton = make_unique<Button>("Okay Button", 0);` ? `std::vector<unique_ptr<Button>> _Buttons;`? `wand.addButton(OkButton);`?

Comment: That's a bit longer. take a look what `make_unique` returns.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for your time already! I'll read up on it and see if I can figure it out on my own.

Comment: @BrianNeltner - Your `Button` class uses pointers, and right now, it may seem ok, but will have issues if you ever need to create strings dynamically using `new char[]`.  The easy fix to this is to use `std::string` instead of `char*` for string data.

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciated. Right now I think if I can grasp unique_ptr I'll be pretty happy! What I'm reading so far makes it sound like I need to create Button Object as a unique_ptr using `std::unique_ptr<Button> OkButton = make_unique<Button>("Okay Button", 0);`. And then I'd have a `std::vector<unique_ptr<Button>> _Buttons;`. Still not quite clear on how to do that move of the unique_ptr from outside to inside the class, and the whole object ownership thing is a little new to me so I'm not sure where I can access it, but I'll keep reading!

Answer (score 0):

When you add the button to the wand you are adding a copy into the vector, thus the address of the Buttons in the vector are not the same as the address of OkButton and NoOkButton.

As others have pointed out using a std::vector< std::unique_ptr > is probably the most robust solution. However, if you really want to use a vector< Button > you could create the editable references to the buttons **after** the vector is completed. This is slightly dangerous though because a std::vector guarantees contiguous memory, therefore the addresses of individual elements can change when a new element is added if there is not room for it.  Here is the code (untested):

```
#include <vector>

class Button {
  private:
    bool _active;
    std::string _title;
    float _value;
  public:
    Button(std::string title, float value) : _title(title) , _value(value) {}
    void setButton(bool active) {
      _active = active;
    };
    std::string getTitle(void) {
      return _title;
    };
    float getValue(void) {
      return _value;
    };
    void setValue(float newvalue) {
       _value = newvalue;
    };
};

class Wand {
  private:
    std::vector< Button > _Buttons;
  public:
    Wand() {};
    void addButton( std::string title, float value ) {
      _Buttons.push_back( Button( title, value ) );
    };
    Button& getButton(int number) {
      return _Buttons[number];
    };
    int numButtons(void) {
      return _Buttons.size();
    };
};


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  SerialUSB.begin(9600);

  Wand wand = Wand();
  wand.addButton("Okay Button", 0);
  wand.addButton("Nokay Button", 0);

  // If you add buttons after this, these references 
  // may be invalid.
  Button& OkButton = wand.getButton(0);
  Button& NokayButton = wand.getButton(1);

  while(1) {
    SerialUSB.println(wand.getButton(0).getValue());
    SerialUSB.println(OkButton.getValue());
    OkButton.setValue(OkButton.getValue()+1);
    SerialUSB.println(wand.getButton(1).getValue());
    SerialUSB.println(NokayButton.getValue());
    NokayButton.setValue(NokayButton.getValue()-1);
    delay(500);
  }

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I also took the liberty to demonstrate some other features of the stl.  A std::string is often more convenient than a char*, and vectors are aware of their size so you don't need to explicitly track the number of buttons.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and makes good sense to me. I like the design better than what I was trying to do for sure. I edited my post with some further questions about some odd behavior I see using this design that I think have to do with subtleties of .back or .push_back that I'm not quite getting.

Comment: I forgot that std::vector can move memory around when adding elements if there is not enough room.  When that happens the original reference is no longer valid.  I've updated my answer to one that should work, but it is still not an optimal solution.